# Given a string, return true if the number of appearances of "is" anywhere in the string is equal to the number of appearances of "not".?

Tags: java

**This is a correct answer I found to that question above. Can anyone please explain why they subtracted lengths and divided by 3 and 2 ?**

```
String strNotMissing = str.replaceAll("not", "");
String strIsMissing = str.replaceAll("is", "");

int notCount = (str.length() - strNotMissing.length()) / 3;
int isCount = (str.length() - strIsMissing.length()) / 2;

return isCount == notCount;
```

Comment: Think about it: What is the Length of the Strings "not" and "is"?

Answer (score 1):

character count of string "not" is 3 and for string "is" is 2 that's why.